# Windows vs. Linux DNS lookups

Tags: linux, networking, dns

How do I configure a Linux machine to pretend to be part of a domain for the purposes of DNS lookup?

The network is running on a Windows AD domain and has no special configuration (other than being joined to the domain) on the Windows side.  The Windows PC automatically picks up the local suffix of `company.local` (as seen in `ipconfig /all`) and `ping servername` and `ping servername.company.local` both work as expected.

As far as I am aware the DHCP server is providing the correct domain name, although I'm not sure how to verify this explicitly.

On a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04) connected to the same network, also with DHCP, I can `ping servername` successfully (so the DHCP and basic DNS is working) but `ping servername.company.local` fails (unknown host).

Initially `dnsdomainname` was blank.  I tried modifying `/etc/hosts` to add the domain name, and while this updated `dnsdomainname` and `/etc/resolv.conf` and successfully lets it ping itself+`.company.local` it still doesn't work for any other addresses.  I also tried setting the "Additional search domains" in the "IPv4/IPv6 Settings" tabs in the network manager UI.

Perhaps most irritatingly, when I `ping servername` it says that it's pinging `servername.localdomain` but then also prints `64 bytes from servername.company.local`.  So some part of the system knows the suffix, but apparently not the right part.

What's the right way to get `ping servername.company.local` to work on Linux machines?

(I need the FQDN to work because various files contain links using the FQDN, because this is needed when using a VPN to connect to the network externally.)

Comment: Are the Windows PC and the Linux box using the same DNS server? I.e. `ifconfig /all` vs `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you are talking about a laptop,then the best solution is to have it pick up the network configuration from the local router, which is clearly currently not providing it.

But if this is, as I suspect, a pc which is not destined to be moved, then you can act locally, even if you do not intend to set up a static IP address for your machine. Edit the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, which should exist even though it is empty except for a comment, and add to it the following lines:

```
   domain company.local
   search company.local
```

When you reboot your Ubuntu pc (because of a bug in the `resolvconf` package, you **cannot** just restart your network to see the changes, you **must** reboot your pc), you will notice that the file `/etc/resolv.conf` now contains the lines

```
   domain company.local
   search company.local
   nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

or something like this. In other words, the `head` file is added at the beginning of your (all-important) `resolv.conf` file. This should fix your problem.